# Where should be period be placed when a sentence ends with a quote in parentheses?

Tags: punctuation, quotation-marks, parentheses, periods

As the title suggests, where should a period be placed when a sentence ends with a quote inside of parentheses? For example (and yes, I know this is a weird example):

Henry tripped on his shoelace and fell, skinning his knee (and saying "oww")

The period has been removed because I don't know where it should go. I can see two possibilities that make sense here:

1. Henry tripped on his shoelace and fell, skinning his knee (and saying "oww").
2. Henry tripped on his shoelace and fell, skinning his knee (and saying "oww.")

I would assume that whatever ruling on this applies for periods, the same ruling would go for commas, although this is a pretty weird one so maybe that's not the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The period would go at the very end of the sentence (your option 1).

As everything in the parentheses, and the parentheses themselves are part of the sentence.